# Como puedo unir 25 grafos en un solo grafo en python 3

Tags: python-3.x, teoría-de-grafos

Buen dia con todos.

Ejemplo de 4 grafos creados:

```py
    import networkx as nx
    # Datos
        a1 = [(6, 9, {'weight': 36.29494914713223}),
         (6, 3, {'weight': 75.16750129516174}),
         (6, 0, {'weight': 50.20339006227196}),
         (9, 3, {'weight': 38.87301006500223}),
         (9, 1, {'weight': 70.85448435080257}),
         (9, 7, {'weight': 26.028665131297405}),
         (9, 4, {'weight': 20.791132829478148}),
         (9, 0, {'weight': 9.908641325304323}),
         (3, 0, {'weight': 24.964368739697903}),
         (2, 8, {'weight': 75.53094526638837}),
         (2, 11, {'weight': 35.94943487968376}),
         (8, 11, {'weight': 35.58172290967591}),
         (1, 11, {'weight': 20.34381187760464}),
         (1, 10, {'weight': 116.14657673017248}),
         (1, 4, {'weight': 50.06469744253988}),
         (1, 7, {'weight': 96.88224624559948}),
         (11, 4, {'weight': 25.726359262891698}),
         (10, 5, {'weight': 34.21904756975249}),
         (10, 7, {'weight': 19.26472900749316})]
        
        a2 = [(6, 9, {'weight': 37.28742287856482}),
         (6, 13, {'weight': 16.76452458024373}),
         (6, 15, {'weight': 74.9218342189813}),
         (9, 13, {'weight': 16.525003620951445}),
         (9, 15, {'weight': 41.6355446689878}),
         (10, 18, {'weight': 33.530464488432095}),
         (10, 1, {'weight': 46.87563982904692}),
         (18, 12, {'weight': 6.334740998759265}),
         (18, 1, {'weight': 9.345358203200767}),
         (18, 2, {'weight': 26.751027103994268}),
         (12, 17, {'weight': 116.74792025885128}),
         (12, 2, {'weight': 37.08489419122768}),
         (12, 4, {'weight': 74.01575793774623}),
         (12, 3, {'weight': 109.4856146710881}),
         (12, 14, {'weight': 55.256862271401324}),
         (12, 5, {'weight': 105.42612583272854}),
         (17, 8, {'weight': 87.17229857323842}),
         (17, 3, {'weight': 7.262341366316788}),
         (17, 16, {'weight': 17.14630351626026}),
         (8, 15, {'weight': 13.368272043602564}),
         (8, 16, {'weight': 70.08175226210291}),
         (8, 7, {'weight': 50.524867020989475}),
         (15, 7, {'weight': 33.166370903759656}),
         (11, 0, {'weight': 42.623268873250595}),
         (11, 14, {'weight': 3.7182048181073957}),
         (11, 13, {'weight': 76.90499013010196}),
         (0, 13, {'weight': 34.28174146981036}),
         (0, 14, {'weight': 34.90546761509087}),
         (2, 14, {'weight': 18.17204144320754}),
         (4, 14, {'weight': 18.759201945364445}),
         (4, 5, {'weight': 31.41062706205524}),
         (16, 7, {'weight': 19.558051021149346}),
         (3, 5, {'weight': 4.059511070361719})]
        
        a3 = [(1, 3, {'weight': 50.990047761815894}),
         (1, 6, {'weight': 21.54182387089422}),
         (1, 8, {'weight': 117.41826921752704}),
         (1, 4, {'weight': 96.82360156464468}),
         (1, 7, {'weight': 70.96856326872953}),
         (3, 8, {'weight': 70.4350459370196}),
         (3, 6, {'weight': 25.449245485114076}),
         (3, 7, {'weight': 19.978773478973554}),
         (5, 6, {'weight': 40.80631205187525}),
         (5, 0, {'weight': 28.691836226626858}),
         (6, 8, {'weight': 95.88187615913291}),
         (6, 0, {'weight': 8.114475825248393}),
         (8, 7, {'weight': 50.460022464529736}),
         (8, 4, {'weight': 20.597967279707735}),
         (4, 7, {'weight': 25.862055184822}),
         (7, 2, {'weight': 35.80315036609218})]
        
        a4 = [(10, 11, {'weight': 94.17719748343532}),
         (10, 6, {'weight': 80.80997549807121}),
         (10, 8, {'weight': 117.67060442786163}),
         (10, 2, {'weight': 37.86038689221032}),
         (11, 1, {'weight': 62.94657673554696}),
         (11, 8, {'weight': 23.498009864555897}),
         (11, 7, {'weight': 23.187367680952036}),
         (11, 6, {'weight': 13.36722198536411}),
         (11, 0, {'weight': 22.755153205051172}),
         (6, 8, {'weight': 40.863127924936784}),
         (6, 2, {'weight': 38.94958860586089}),
         (4, 12, {'weight': 23.286031815454105}),
         (4, 5, {'weight': 49.985854772293465}),
         (12, 5, {'weight': 22.699866237641434}),
         (12, 1, {'weight': 8.406861158369775}),
         (12, 0, {'weight': 27.785791515874365}),
         (1, 9, {'weight': 109.46290542810175}),
         (1, 0, {'weight': 40.191552069454175}),
         (1, 7, {'weight': 86.13296928881624}),
         (8, 2, {'weight': 79.81081647223037}),
         (3, 9, {'weight': 12.799372033947222}),
         (9, 7, {'weight': 23.330484527277907})]

    # Creacion de grafos
        g = [a1,a2,a3,a4]
        b = []
        for i in range(len(g)):
            G = nx.Graph()
            G.add_edges_from(list((a,b) for a, b, w in g[i]))
            G.add_weighted_edges_from(list((a,b,w['weight']) for a, b, w in g[i]))
            b.append(G)

    
        nx.draw_networkx(b[0])
```

Ejemplo de grafico

[image: Grafico de grafo generado]

De este tipo de información se ha creado el grafo, teniendo en cuenta que los nodos son diferentes para los 4 grafos.

Y con ello se han creado 25 grafos en algunos casos que se repiten nodos (puntos georeferenciados), lo que trato es unir todos estos 25 grafos, en un solo grafo que contengan todos los puntos y pesos de los lados.

```
    DFF = []
    b = 0 
    for a in range[24]:
        DF2 = nx.disjoint_union(G_PC[a], G_PC[b+1]) # no interesa que se mantenga el numero de nodos
        DFF.append(DF2)
```

Tal vez alguien me pueda guiar como lo puedo unir estos grafos en uno solo.

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Saludos

Comment: Con el código que has puesto no es posible reproducir el problema, por favor agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el comportamiento que reportas y para poder ver cómo ayudarte de mejor forma.

Comment: Buen dia, he añadido información para reproducir el problema, muchas gracias por su ayuda.